# How to use StringFormat in a binding in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, devexpress

I've the following code, that is to set the Header of a column with a DevExpress Grid:

```
<dxg:GridControl SelectedItem="{Binding something}" SelectionMode="Row"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyElementCollection}" Name ="devExpressGrid">
    <!-- ... -->
    <dxg:GridColumn  Header="{Binding DataContext.ViewModelProperty.Symbol, ElementName=devExpressGrid, StringFormat={x:Static common:My.Text}}" Width="*" AllowEditing="True">
    <!-- ... -->
</dxg:GridControl>
```

But when I display it, I only have the content of my Binding.

Then I tried

```
<dxg:GridControl SelectedItem="{Binding something}" SelectionMode="Row"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyElementCollection}" Name ="devExpressGrid">
    <!-- ... -->
    <dxg:GridColumn  Header="{Binding DataContext.ViewModelProperty.Symbol, ElementName=devExpressGrid, StringFormat={}test {0}" Width="*" AllowEditing="True">
    <!-- ... -->
</dxg:GridControl>
```

To exclude the resource variable, but I've the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: A Binding's StringFormat is only used if the target property is of type string. Use a Binding Converter instead. Or perhaps put a TextBlock into the Header.

Comment: StringFormats are *not* applied to `string` properties